# AngularJS ng-show if a property within an object array is set to false

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I want to hide a `div` if no object within a `array` has a specific property set to `false`.

The property looks like this:

```
$scope.myObjArray = [
    {"Id":"1","IsBuiltIn":true},
    {"Id":"2","IsBuiltIn":true}
];
```

I want to hide my `div` if there is no object within `myObjArray` that has `IsBuiltIn` set to `false`. So the above `array` should hide the `div`. The following should show it (because at least one object has `IsBuiltIn`set to false):

```
$scope.myObjArray = [
    {"Id":"1","IsBuiltIn":true},
    {"Id":"2","IsBuiltIn":true},
    {"Id":"3","IsBuiltIn":false}
];
```

I tried to solve this using a `ForEach` without success:

```
<div ng-show="myObjArray.ForEach(e, function(){e.IsBuiltIn})">
    Hello, World!
</div>
```

Here is my [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2LgFSdhIjQjhVuaXWgEg).

Comment: Place your logic into a scope function that returns a true or false. It's not working cause you are using an array ForEach. Too lazy to code. xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Controller, create a function to check if any of the object in the array has `false` value for the property `IsBuiltIn` using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
$scope.containsFalsy = (arr) => arr.some(o => o.IsBuiltIn === false);
```

This is using ES6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax. The above function is equivalent to

```
$scope.containsFalsy = function (arr) {
    return arr.some(function (obj) {
        return obj.IsBuiltIn === false;
    });
};
```

Call the function from the View

```
<div ng-hide="containsFalsy(myObjArray)">
```

[**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dPQHp8FDO7XJZy8YlLsm?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.myObjArray = [{
    "Id": "1",
    "IsBuiltIn": true
  }, {
    "Id": "2",
    "IsBuiltIn": true
  }];

  $scope.myObjArray1 = [{
    "Id": "1",
    "IsBuiltIn": true
  }, {
    "Id": "2",
    "IsBuiltIn": true
  }, {
    "Id": "3",
    "IsBuiltIn": false
  }];

  $scope.containsFalsy = (arr) => arr.some(o => o.IsBuiltIn === false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-hide="containsFalsy(myObjArray)">
      Hello, World!
    </div>


    <div ng-hide="containsFalsy(myObjArray1)">
      Can you see me?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar, looks solid :-). Is there no way to check this within the `ng-hide` directive (without a controller function?)

Comment: No @jisaak tushar's right, you need the controller function to do it for you - don't pollute templates with lots of logic.